# Using a browser inside Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, puppeteer, headless-browser

I want to build a web crawler/scraper web application using angular. Idea is to use client-side for making all http requests. Using a headless browser can take away much of the pain in parsing Html and evaluation JS code. Are there any headless JS-based browsers I can use? 
I read about headless chrome and puppeteer. It turns out it can be used only from command line for running tests and not like a typical library which can work with angular. Or is there a way?

Comment: Simple question - I assume you're after something more than just an iframe? Edit: I see you want to scrape the content, so iframe not suitable.

Answer (score 1):

I am a scraper myself. This is how I solved the problem

1. get the html content using http/fetch
2. create an Iframe
3. Provide the string html content.

I am currently creating a solution using the same strategy above. Hope it helps.

Edit1: Do let me know in case you need a working demo. I feel its straightforward.

Comment: How do you start the Angular/Puppeteer application? All the examples I see start the application with `ng test app` but I don't want to test it, I want to use it to generate PDFs/images at server side